# Using REST api to build a web app

Tags: rest, api

What happens when we do not use REST api to build a web application? And also please tell how to build a web service using REST api in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

***What happens when we do not use REST api to build a web application?***

Nothing, you can do your project with or without REST API. Assume you are running a restaurant and you want to attach with online food service like Foodpanda,zomato you need to provide an API to interact your data without any user interface which can be done easily using REST.

**Why do we need RESTful web services?**

REST should be used if it is very important for you to minimize the coupling between client and server components in a distributed application. [[read more]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368014/why-do-we-need-restful-web-services)

**How to build a web service using REST api in PHP?**

There are many resources available in internet. Here I found something related to PHP

[PHP RESTful Web Service](http://phppot.com/php/php-restful-web-service)

Comment: Thank you sir. I found the use of REST after practicing and implementing REST principles.